# Is it possible to inherit or extend a style from custom attribute

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I'm making a library which requires a parent style to be passed into the library through the theme. To achieve that, `x` is the style defined within the library. But it needs to extend something from the parent.

**Is it possible to do the below?**

My library style :-

```
<style="x" parent="?customAttrReferingToSomeOtherStyle"></style>
```

Anyone using my library needs to do this :-

```
<item name="customAttrReferingToSomeOtherStyle">@style/ApprelatedStyle</item>
```

I'm not interested in hard coding a parent style. I want it to be purely referrential based on custom attributes. Any form of hard-coding a style would defeat Separation of Concerns in module a setup.

Comment: Question is unclear, can you rephrase?

Comment: What is unclear?

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: lol, my bad, it didnt submit my latest edit, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: What’s the problem you have faced?

Comment: inheritance is available for styles. if you want to inherit from a (custom) attribute(i don't understand why somebody want to do that), you must wrap it up in a style then inherit that style.

Comment: @MehranZamani can you write an example snippet for that? As to why I would do it - its to keep the module independent of the parent style

Comment: `<style name="GreenText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    </style>`

Comment: `<style name="TextAppearance" <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item> </style>`

Comment: This is not inheritence from a custom attribute

Comment: you put your custom attribute in a style and then inherits the style. there is no way to derive from an attribute. am i explaining well?

Comment: Are you saying what i'm asking is not possible?